# Network topologies

Tags: probability, general-topology, graph-theory

You are tasked with evaluating the following two proposed network topologies, for a network of 100 nodes:

Option A: a ring topology: i.e., for 1 ≤ i ≤ 99, one cable connects node i and node i + 1, and one cable connects node 100 and node 1.

Option B: all pairs of nodes are directly connected with a cable.

Each cable costs 1 dollar per day to maintain. On any given day, each cable fails with probability 0.1%, independently of any other cable. A partition occurs if for some two nodes, all paths in the network from one node to the other pass through a failed cable. The cost of a partition is $1,000,000.

Find the expected cost per day of both topologies, rounded to the nearest dollar. Which is cheaper to maintain? (You may assume that a partition will never occur for Option B.) Show your work and explain your answer.

Been tackling this one for a while. I have done a few explorations, and I'm thinking the ring topology is easier to maintain even with the possibility of partition, though I cannot find a mathematical proof to explain this. Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

Comment: The ring has a partition iff at least 2 cables fail. You should be able to exactly compute the probability of 0 or 1 cable failures (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

Ring
Likelyhood of a partition is about 1 in a million.
Expected per day cost of a partition is a dollar. 
Expected cost per day 100 + 1.

Other
Likelyhood of a partition is amost zero.
Expected per day cost of a partition is
almost nothing (a small fraction of a mil).
Expected cost per day 4950 + almost nothing.

Comment: How did you calculate that it would take 5000 wires for option B?

Comment: @J.Sanders.  (100 * 100)/2..  Actually it should be (100 * 99)/2 = 4950 = 100_C_2.